# How can I get backward-delete-word to add to the current kill-ring in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I use zsh and I would like backward-kill-word in Emacs mode to behave like Emacs (and bash, fwiw).  The behaviour that I have failed to reproduce is that when I press multiple backward-kill-word Emacs adds the killed text to the cut buffer (the first item in the killring) making it possible for me to yank everything with one yank command.

How can I configure zsh to behave like this aspect of Emacs editors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, by default, Zsh's cut buffer works exactly the same as in Emacs. Just use `zsh -f` to start Zsh without config files and try it.

However, are you perhaps using `zsh-autosuggestions` or `zsh-syntax-highlighting`? There are bugs in these plugins that break this feature:

- https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions/issues/363
- https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/issues/150#issuecomment-658381485

Fixes have been submitted, but for `zsh-autosuggestions`, none have yet been merged, and for `zsh-syntax-highlighting`, the fix won't work until Zsh 5.9 has been released.

In the meantime, though, [`zsh-autocomplete`](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete) contains a workaround that fixes the problem. If you add that plugin, your cut buffer will start functioning like normal again.

Comment: Thanks!  This solved my problem.  I was using zsh-syntax-highlighting via antigen. Disabling zsh-syntax-highlighting was not enough, I had to also stop using antigen at all. I tested with `antigen apply` without any bundles and that was enough to manifest the problem in a zsh -f

Comment: If you're interested in finding another plugin manager, give [Znap](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-snap) a try. 

Comment: Can you point to where in the `zsh-autocomplete` code the fix is? Installing it didn't fix the bug for me (it's a cool plugin though :) so I'm trying to figure out where the issue is

Comment: Here: https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete/blob/main/functions/.autocomplete.zle-flags